# How to group by for different conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table 1 as follow, I want to group the total money for prospect in one group. **However, am facing difficulties to group all money in won status as in Won stage.**
[image]

I want result like below:

[image]

```
SELECT 
name,sum(value),stagename
  FROM table1
  group by name,stagename
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to aggregate on a combination of the `status` and `stagename` columns:

```
select name,
       (case when status = 'won' then 'won' else stagename end) as stagename,
       sum(value)
from table1
group by name,
      (case when status = 'won' then 'won' else stagename end);
```

Comment: Was just thinking about this. +1

Comment: Hi @sara if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Well there isn't obligation but accept answers are important because beside the reputation other stop trying to find a solution.

Comment: @Juan Agreed. . .

Comment: @Gordin Linoff , this query is fine but it showed me results for multiple 'won' and 'Won 100%' , and I wanted them to be all aggregated so I opened another thread to show a clear data.

Answer (score 2):

You can query like this:

```
select name, stagename, sum(value) from #yourstages
    where status = 'open'
    group by name, stagename

union all

select name, status as StageName, sum(value) from #yourstages
    where status = 'won'
    group by name, status
```

Answer (score 1):

For multiple stagename values:

```
SELECT T1.name, CASE WHEN T1.STAGENAME=T2.STATUS THEN SUM(T2.VALUE) ELSE SUM(T1.value) END AS VALUE, T1.STAGENAME
  FROM table1 T1 LEFT JOIN TABLE1 T2 ON T2.STATUS=T1.STAGENAME
  group by T1.name,T2.STATUS, T1.stagename
```